# Restart loop from the previous state if a condition is not met

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The problem statement is that if a condition is not true, it should "stop" the for loop or should not progress unless that value is met.

Lets say that there is an input statement of true/false or a boolean statement in a for loop that prints to 1 to 10.

If the condition goes false in the the 5th iteration, it should stay at 5th iteration until the boolean returns true.

```
for i in {1..10}
do
        read jobstatus
#       echo $i
        if [ "$jobstatus" = true ] ; then
                echo 'Okay lets progress'
        else
                echo 'Nop, cant progress'
                ((i--))
        #       continue
#print $i
        fi
        echo $i
done
```

I have tried making codes such as this, also checked it via making files that were acting as "flags" But I cant seem to "stop" the progression. I dont want to break the loop, I just want to make it stay at that specific iteration until and unless the state changes.
Like if the job status goes falses at i=5, i should stay at 5 unless jobstatus gets to true. ( I intend to check the jobstatus at each input)

Comment: Using a while loop, within your for loop. Id recommend using an if before to check the job status to print out if it can't progress first, then a while loop that waits until jobstatus is true before echoing it can progress. I might add using a delay as you don't want to check the status too often and consume some of your processing power.

Answer (score 2):

You could structure the loops something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while test "$i" -lt 10; do
        while read jobstatus && test "$jobstatus" != true; do
                echo "can't progress.  jobstatus = $jobstatus" >&2
        done
        if test "$jobstatus" = true; then
                echo "Okay lets progress to step $((++i))"
        else
                echo Unexpected End of input >&2
                exit 1
        fi
        echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Nice, increment, `++1`, but it does not work in posix though, how sad...

Answer (score 1):

Use a C-style for-loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=10; ++i)) ; do
    read jobstatus
    if [ "$jobstatus" = true ] ; then
        echo 'Okay lets progress'
    else
        echo 'Nop, cant progress'
        ((i--))
    fi
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` test should to be a loop of some sort.
For example:

```bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    while
        read jobstatus
        [ "$jobstatus" != true ]
    do
        echo 'Nop, cant progress'    
    done
    echo 'Okay lets progress'

    echo $i
done
```

If you want to repeat the other `for` commands (ie. the `echo $i` statement here) until the test succeeds, they should go inside the loop too. For example:

```bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    while
        echo $i
        read jobstatus
        [ "$jobstatus" != true ]
    do
        echo 'Nop, cant progress'
    done
    echo 'Okay lets progress'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  read jobstatus
  if [ "$jobstatus" != true ]; then
    echo 'Nop, cant progress'
  fi

  while [ "$jobstatus" != "true" ]; do
    read jobstatus
    sleep 1
    # echo statements here if needed
  done

  echo 'Okay lets progress'
  echo $i
done
```

No need to decrement `i` , this also avoids checking the status of `jobstatus` too often potentially consuming an unnecessary amount of resources.

Answer (score 0):

With an interactive user input, Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 10 ] && printf 'Enter status: '; do
  IFS= read -r jobstatus
  case "$jobstatus" in
    true)
    i=$((i+1))
    printf 'Okay lets progress to %s' "$i";;
  *)
    printf >&2 'Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: %s' "${jobstatus:-empty}"
  esac
  printf '\n'
done
```

---

Using a text file for the input, to test the script.

The `file.txt`

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
foo
bar
baz

true
true
true
true
qux

true
false
```

---

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 10 ] && IFS= read -r jobstatus; do
  case "$jobstatus" in
    true)
    i=$((i+1))
    printf 'Okay lets progress to %s' "$i";;
  *)
    printf >&2 'Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: %s' "${jobstatus:-empty}";;
  esac
  printf '\n'
done < file.txt
```

---

Output:

```
Okay lets progress to 1
Okay lets progress to 2
Okay lets progress to 3
Okay lets progress to 4
Okay lets progress to 5
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: false
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: foo
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: bar
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: baz
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: empty
Okay lets progress to 6
Okay lets progress to 7
Okay lets progress to 8
Okay lets progress to 9
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: qux
Nop, cant progress because jobstatus is: empty
Okay lets progress to 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

for ((truecount=0; truecount<10;)); do
    read -r jobstatus
    if [[ $jobstatus == true ]]; then
        echo "Okay let's progress"
        (( ++truecount ))
    else
        echo "Nope, can't progress"
    fi
    printf '%d\n' "$truecount"
done
```

- The major change from the original code is that it advances only on 'true' status instead of always advancing and stepping back on non-'true' status.  In general, it's best if you can modify a loop variable in only one place.
- Since the code isn't just stepping through a sequence, I replaced the meaningless `i` with the descriptive `truecount`.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to print the count value.  (`echo "$truecount"` would probably be OK in this specific case, but `echo "$var"` doesn't work in general so I never use it.  `echo $var` is bad.  See [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).)